# Why is Disney redoing live-action versions of fairytales they've already done?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, disney

A huge part of what Disney does is create film adaptations of well known children's fairytales. First it was mostly 2D animation, then it branched out to include 3D animation and live-action adaptations of fairytales.

Recenetly, however, Disney has begun making live-action versions of fairytales that the *already* have adapted to film.

For example:

- Snow White and the Huntsman
- Maleficent (Sleeping Beauty)
- Alice in Wonderland
- Cinderella
- Jungle Book
- Beauty and the Beast
- etc.

**Has Disney commented as to *why* they are doing this?** Do they consider the older adaptation inadequate or outdated and so they're seeking to 'modernized' them or something?

---

<sub>**NOTE:** When I asked this question I thought about including "besides wanting to make more money, why is Disney..." so that's why I said "Has Disney **commented** as to why they are doing this?"</sub>

Comment: You're joking, I assume? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPX5mRSQ3pw

Comment: Maleficent and Sleeping Beauty, to take just one example, while nominally based on the same original source are nonetheless completely different movies.  Even apart from the money motive, I can easily understand why someone might have wanted to make Maleficient on purely artistic grounds.  I *don't* see any reason why a company should or would feel obliged to avoid nominal repetitions of this sort, or for that matter to comment on them.

Comment: Snow White and the Huntsman was a Universal production, not Disney.

Answer (score 6):

Money.

While Disney are probably making a nice bit of income from DVD and/or blu-ray sales of their old movies, they do have to keep generating new content to get the really big bucks that a worldwide cinema release and then subsequent blu-ray launch will provide.

Why are they returning to old IP for new movies?

1. All of the original (pre-disney animation) IP is public domain - they don't have to pay royalties to use Cinderella or Sleeping Beauty, or any of those others you list.
2. They also own the rights to those animated adaptations - so again, no royalties to pay to other creators.

Finally, why live action? Why the "darker" approach?

Audiences and expectations have changed over the years. While we still might enjoy the original Dumbo or Alice, Disney want to appeal to the market which is saturated with darker, grittier movies and TV shows.

The older animated movies are targeted for a younger audience (pre-teens, really) and their parents. The newer, darker ones are for teens and young adults - a market segment that didn't exist or have money in the "golden" age of Disney animation. And there's always the perception that animation = targeted for kids.

**Has Disney *commented*?**

Not really. But their motivations seem to be based on:

1) Disney animation has a bad rap after pumping out sub-par sequels to successful movies.

2) Disney does have Pixar.

3) Disney's initial foray into live action retellings have been very successful.

[From last year](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/jul/23/rating-disney-slate-of-live-action-fantasy-remakes-animated-originals):

> Disney is confident because its early forays into the nascent genre –
>   if it can even be called that – haven’t offered up a single box-office
>   dud. Alice in Wonderland pulled in more than $1bn; Kenneth Branagh’s
>   Cinderella comfortably passed $500m earlier this year, and Maleficent
>   scored a whopping $758m worldwide.

[This article](http://www.smh.com.au/entertainment/movies/disney-remakes-why-liveaction-versions-of-dumbo-jungle-book-and-beauty-and-the-beast-are-coming-to-the-big-screen-20150402-1md1z0.html) does list some other reasons Disney might be doing this - but ultimately, each of them translates into "money".

Comment: Has Disney __commented__ as to why they are doing this?

Comment: @RedCaio - Production companies rarely say things like "We're making this movie because you shmucks will eat it up, and we want more of your money".

Comment: @RedCaio: Why does any for-profit company release a new product?

Comment: @Ellesedil when I asked the question I thought about including "besides wanting to make more money, why is Disney..." so that's _why_ I said "Has Disney _commented_ as to why they are doing this?"

Comment: @RedCaio - do you want to clarify that in your original question - "Why is Disney redoing live-action versions of fairytales they've already done?"?

Comment: @HorusKol Well, I try to avoid changing questions in a way that invalidates an existing answer. If it wouldn't bother you, I can clarify my question. If you want, feel free to add to your answer to address whether or not Disney has made any comments on the subject.